# building apps with kivy to intract with Django Restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, kivy

so I have a project that developed with django ,Django Restframework.

I had planned for UI handling. Reactjs and Reatnative for UI .but I searched and found Kivy project that comes with Cross Platforms for making Apps and games.my project doesn't involve any game stuff just regular web site.

**is it good using kivy for handling UI for Android and IOs?**

I also checked kivy supports fully Url request for interact with Rest APIs.
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html

Answer (score 3):

Kivy is really good alternative to android native programming language for python programmers. You need ubuntu to build apk for kivy apps. However, installing ubuntu or virtual environment is not mandatory if you use windows 10 because windows 10 have linux subsystem. You can check it on this video[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQ68bJE8g7c).

Kivy is general framework which is not specific to games or graphical application only. Kivy support regular mobile application development, we can check it by the provided [widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.html). The widgets are also customizable So, kivy is a pretty good alternative.